# How to assign a sequence number to every message that passes a netty message decoder?

Tags: java, netty, sequence

I am working on a netty channel handler/decoder that assigns a unique sequence number to every message arrives at the handler.

My current approach defines an attribute holding an AtomicLong as a counter and whenever a message arrives, it is incremented by one and assigned to the decoded message:

```
@Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, TextWebSocketFrame frame, List<Object> out) {
    AttributeKey<AtomicLong> sequenceKey = AttributeKey.valueOf("message_sequence");
    AtomicLong sequence = ctx.channel().attr(sequenceKey).get();
    long curerntMessageId = sequence.incrementAndGet();

    Message message = decode(frame);
    message.setMessageId(curerntMessageId);
```

Later, in the message encoder, the message id is transferred to the response message, thus connecting a request and a response via an unique id.

The reason to go with this approach is that in the context of a web-socket connection, I need some mechanics to identify a request<->response cycle.

I wonder if this approach makes sense though, as I have to access the channel attributes all the time or if there is maybe already an existing solution out there, that I am maybe not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this only needs to be unique per connection you could just store an int / long directly in the decoder itself and increment it. This works as everything is single threaded. So there is no need to use an attribute and an atomic at all if I understood your use-case correctly

Comment: I thought about this as well, but the problem is, that I only have one single instance of this encoder which is also annotated with @Sharable. It might be an acceptable trade-off though to have one encoder per connection instead of an attribute with an AtomicLong attached to the channel.

Comment: the Attribute is not for free either and may be more expensive to maintain then the decoder instance...

Comment: ok, I'll go with the decoder per channel approach, as I do not have to access any other channel attributes inside this encoder. Thx for pointing me in this direction!